# eclipse keep on updating and creating

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am try to use maven in eclipse (luna,mars and neon),I configure maven settings.xml mirror with [maven repository url](http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/).and then I configure eclipse about maven,such as settings file path ,local repo path ,unchecked auto build project and so on. but times I want to create maven-archetype-webapp project,it blocked at creating maven-archetype-webapp with 99% schedule more than 1 hour,then I use git bash archetype:generate command create a maven-archetype-wenapp project , and import to eclipse , when I update project (or use Alt+F5),it blocked at updating maven project . so how to create webapp archetype without block,or how to update without block?thanks!!!

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with the latest Eclipse version (Oxygen)?

Comment: @howlger thanks.I found that eclipse can create quickstart project,but can not create webapp project.and I found that with maven-archetype-webapp project,the dynamic web project version is 2.5,but default web dynamic web project version is 3.0.is there any enfluence?but I can not change the maven -archetype-webapp version